# If a string contains the same value as cells k4:k7, give true

Tags: excel, compare, contain

This is what I tried but this doenst work:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH($K$4:$K$7;L4))
```

I want to check if E4 contains the same string as K4 thru K7. Is this somehow possible? I know that this is possible: `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(K4;L4))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=ISNUMBER(LOOKUP(1;0/SEARCH(L4;$K$4:$K$7)))`

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Try a match formula. It should be very similar to the way you're using the search formula.

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(L4,$K$4:$K$7,0))
```

Comment: Did you try replacing the commas in my formula with semicolons?

Comment: Yes I did, even when I got `1` in K4 and `sdf1sdf` in M4 it doenst work anymore now ? With this: `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(L4;K4))` it outcomes `false`..

Comment: @wouter: you told you look in L4 and mention M4 in the comment, please be more clear. if you want to check also part of the cell you need to use `"*"&L4&"*"`.